# Enable filtering when overriding the getView

Tags: android, listview, view, filter, adapter

I have a `ListView` and I am overriding `getView` method which is populating properly with the following code. If I use 'adapter.getfilter()', it dose not update the listview, though in adapter its filtered and are displayed by 'out()' properly when the NEXT filter is done, entering text in the Edit box. Any idea how can I enable filtering when I am overriding the `getView` and filter affecting the adapter on the same time and not the next time when entering text in the edit box ?

```
final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
android.R.layout.activity_list_item,stringArray) 
{   @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {View  row= super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        View row=convertView;
if(position==0){
row = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_header, null);
final TextView sectionView = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.list_item_section_text);
sectionView.setText(myList.get(position));
} 
else
{row = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
final TextView sectionView = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.list_item_entry_title);
sectionView.setText(myList.get(position));}
return row;}});

lv.setAdapter(adapter);
for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++) {//displaying properly
pr("adapter list"+adapter.getItem(i));
}
myFilter.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) { }
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
adapter.getFilter().filter(s);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++) {
pr("adapter list before "+         (adapter.getItem(i)));//printing properly but not  
//updated in listview ,sometimes it just displays first few ,even if it should not be
//in filtered result after filtering.    
} }  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest building a custom filter. Extend the Filter object (I usually do it as an inner class of the adapter) and have that do your filtering. Save a copy of the items you pass into the array and filter from that. Clear your adapter in publishResults, and add the filtered items back in.